# Фильтрация с использованием editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

В активити при вводе заголовков в editText происходит динамическая фильтрация item-ов списка. Но если не существует такого заголовка, то активируется текст "поиск не дал результатов" и кнопка, при нажатии на которую можно написать разработчику, что пользователь не нашел, что хотел.

Проблема номер 1. Если ввести допустим "коты", то такого не найдется, и кнопка активировалась, но если стереть последнюю букву, то должен показаться item с заголовком "кот". Но когда стираю, обновления не происходит. Приходится нажимать назад, опять запускать поиск и вводить "кот".

Проблема номер 2. Если я ввожу "коты" экран пустой, но если потом нажимаю пробел, то появляется та кнопка.

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
private SearchAdapter searchAdapter;
EditText etFilter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ImageView ivNoResult;
TextView tvNoResult;
Button btnNoResult;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);
  ......
     recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);


    // при старте выводим все данные (фильтр - пустая строка)
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
    bundle.putString("filter", "");


    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader( 0, bundle, this);


    etFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            // получаем строку по мере ввода
            refreshCursor(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (searchAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ivNoResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvNoResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnNoResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            btnNoResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{getString(R.string.email)});
                    ........
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_email)));

                }
            });
            }
    });
}

private void refreshCursor(String str) {
    //передаем в загрузчик строку для фильтра и перезапускаем загрузчик для обновления списка
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
    bundle.putString("filter", str);
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, bundle, this);
}
```

Я переносила код из метода afterTextChanged в onTextChanged, поведение приложения не меняется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По пункту 1 - вы обрабатываете условие пустого списка и выводите кнопку, но ничего не делаете, когда список не пустой. Добавьте в условие блок `else` и соответственно показывайте список и скрывайте кнопку.
По пункту 2 - я думаю проблема в асинхронной работе лоудера, то есть проверка проходит раньше, чем адаптер получает данные.

Я бы вам рекомендовал вообще не делать эту проверку в слушателе ввода, а подписаться непосредственно на счетчик айтемов списка и там скрывать\показывать кнопки, примерный упрощенный код:

```
    RvObserver observer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        observer = new RvObserver();
        etFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                refreshCursor(charSequence.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) { }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // подписываемся на изменения в списке
        searchAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // отписываемся от изменений
        searchAdapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(observer);
    }

    class RvObserver extends RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver {

        private void checkIfEmpty() {
            if (searchAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ivNoResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvNoResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnNoResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ivNoResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tvNoResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnNoResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        // здесь, возможно, не во всех трех колбэках нужна проверка, а только в одном из них
        public void onChanged() { checkIfEmpty(); }
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) { checkIfEmpty(); }
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) { checkIfEmpty(); }
    }
}
```

на основе [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28217436/7566397), возможно там вы найдете другие варианты решения